# FBSDKCoreKit Framework, in xCode 7 Protocol FBSDKApplicationDelegate doesn't recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, fbsdk

I downloaded the latest Facebook SDK version 4.6
I followed the Getting Started with IOS SDK reading here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

I dragged and dropped the FBSDKCoreKit.Framework inside the project like the guide show.

In the header of AppDelegate.m i wrote:

```
//-----
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <FBSDKApplicationDelegate>

@end
//----
```

I did all of the guide of Getting started....
Well, my problem is:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate' did you mean 'UIApplicationDelegate'?
```

`FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h` is recognized well, `FBSDKApplicationDelegate.h` is inside the framework, the Framework Search Path is in application settings....

Where is the problem? I can't find it

Info:
XCode 7.0,
FBSdk 4.6,
Deployment Target 9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to implement the delegate as you did.

Instead of:

```
//-----
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <FBSDKApplicationDelegate>

@end
//----
```

You need this

```
//-----
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate () 

@end
//----
```

The returned value in the next method must be

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   // your code

  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Then you have to implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
}
```

That's all.